# How to find a series for an odd and even recurrence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence relation $$a_m = - \frac{a_{m-2}}{m(m+3)}$$

From there I added a term
$$a_m = - \frac{1}{m(m+3)} \cdot - \frac{a_{m-4}}{(m-2)(m+1)}$$

Thus I have $$a_m = \frac{-1^{m/2}}{m!!(m +3)!!}a_0$$
And for m even I have
$$a_{2k} = \frac{-1^{k}}{2k!!(2k +3)!!}a_0$$

I would like to know if I can find the series for m odd using the recurrence relation and if so, is it possible to add up together both series, odd and even, to have only one. Since I have to find a cos or sin series, I don't see any other way than having a series that take both odd and even m.

I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: $(2k)!!(2k+3)!!=(2k+1)!(2k+3).$

Comment: FYI - In English "series" is both singular and plural. You can have one "series", two "series" or any number of "series".  "Serie" is not an English word (at least not for this meaning). But also, I think you mean "sequence", not "series", anyway. A series refers to the sum of a sequence: $\{a_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence. $\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} a_n$ is a series.

Comment: @BazyliZuczek I tried to find that, but I don't know how to get that.
I know that $2k!! = 2^k \cdot k!$, but that's all.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate $\sum a_{2k}$ ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how you get $(2k)!!(2k+3)!!=(2k+1)!(2k+3).$

Comment: Note that the question is coming from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383218/find-2-solutions-of-the-bessel-equation-as-series-of-x

Answer (score 1):

We have $${a_{2k}\over a_0}  ={(-1)^k\over [ 2\cdot 4\cdot \ldots \cdot 2k]\cdot [3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot(2k+1)\cdot (2k+3)]}={(-1)^k\over (2k+1)!} {1\over 2k+3}.$$ We will make use of $$-x\sin x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}{x^{2k+2}\over (2k+1)!}.$$
By applying integration we get
$$-\int\limits_0^1x\sin x\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}{1\over (2k+1)!}{1\over (2k+3)}.$$ Therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {a_{2k}\over a_0}=-\int\limits_0^1x\sin x\,dx  = (x\cos x-\sin x)\Big |_{x=0}^{x=1} 
 =\cos 1-\sin 1$$
The second sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {a_{2k-1}\over a_1}$$
can be calculated in a similar way.
Namely
$${a_{2k-1}\over a_1} ={(-1)^{k-1}\over (2k-1)!!\, (2k+2)!!}={(-1)^{k-1}\over (2k)!(2k+2)}.$$
We have
$$-x(\cos x-1) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}{x^{2k+1}\over (2k)!}.$$
Therefore
$$-\int\limits_0^1x(\cos x-1)\,dx =\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k-1}\over (2k)!(2k+2)}.$$ Hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {a_{2k-1}\over a_1}=-\int\limits_0^1x(\cos x-1)\,dx =\int\limits_0^1(x-x\cos x)\,dx\\ ={1\over 2}-(x\sin x+\cos x)\Big |_{x=0}^{x=1}={3\over 2}-\sin 1-\cos 1.$$