# Find 2 solutions of the Bessel equation as series of $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions, frobenius-method

I'm trying to solve a problem from the textbook mathematics for physicist by Susan Lea and I have a few questions about it.

First of all, I have to find 2 solutions as power of $x$ for the Bessel series $$x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} + (x^2 -\frac{9}{4})y = 0$$ and then I have to verify that my solutions agree with the standard form $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} (\frac{\sin x}{x} - \cos x)
$ and $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} (\frac{\cos x}{x} + \sin x)$ which I'm not sure what that mean.

Here my attempt

Standard form
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} + (x^2 -\frac{9}{4})\frac{y}{x^2} = 0$$

Plugging $$(x-x_0)^p \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n,$$ where $x_0 = 0$ in the first equation I get $$\sum[(n+p)(n+p-1)a_n x^{n+p}] \\ + \sum[(n+p)a_n x^{n+p}] + \sum[a_n x^{n+p+2}] - 9/4 \sum[a_n x^{n+p}] = 0$$

The smallest power is $x^p$ for $n = 0$, thus I find $p = \pm \frac{3}{2}$

For $x^{m+p}$ I have
$$(m+p)(m+p-1)a_m + (m+p)a_m + a_{m-2} - 9/4 a_m = 0$$
$$a_{m-2} = [(m+p(m+p-1) + (m+p) -9/4)] a_m$$

Plugging $p = \frac{3}{2}$ I have my recurrence relation $$a_{m-2} = -m(m+3)a_m$$

From there arise some questions.

From the recurrence relation I'm trying to find a series and those series should be a series of sine or cosine to agree with the standard form.

Thus, $$a_m = -\frac{a_{m-2}}{m(m+3)} = - \frac{1}{m(m+3)} \cdot - \frac{a_{m-4}}{(m-2)(m+1)}$$

For $m$ even
$$a_m = \frac{-1^{m/2}}{m!!(m+3)!!}a_0$$
$m = 2k$
$$a_{2k} = \frac{-1^{k}}{k!!(k+3)!!}a_0$$

As far as I can tell, I can't see a cosine or sine series yet. I'm wondering if I have to find a series for $m$ odd then find a way to put it together with $m$ even, or can I find a solution with $m$ even and one with $m$ odd even if I have 2 $p$ where I have to find a solution for each one.

I hope my question is clear even if it's not perfectly clear in my head.

Comment: Why do you introduce $x_0$ if it is $0$? Little bit of cheating: try looking for solutions in the form $$
x^{1/2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^{2n} } \; \text{ and } \; x^{ - 3/2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {b_n x^{2n} } .
$$

Comment: I introduce $x_0 = 0$ because of the singularity of the standard form.
Something I use from the textbook. I was using the general form. I think I see what you mean with those solutions, I found something similar after looking for examples. However, I'm powerless toward the last equation. As I said I can't find the right way to find the solutions. I know eventually I have to add $x^{p+m}$ to the series, which will me $x^{3/2} \cdot x^{2k}$, but I can't find $a_n$ and $b_n$ which should be cosine and sine function, I guess.

Comment: @Gary To have a cosine or sine series I should have 2k! or (2k +1)! at the dominator, but the only thing I know is that $2k!! = 2^k \cdot k!$

Comment: @gary it shouldn't be $x^{1/2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^{2n+1} }$ ?

Comment: Note that $$
(2k - 1)!! = \frac{{(2k - 1)!}}{{2^{k - 1} (k - 1)!}}.
$$ You are right ragarding the form of the power series.

Comment: @Gary
I think it's an algebra issue.
I still can't find a power series of x.
I mean there's still a k somewhere whatever I do.
I found $y_1 = a_0 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2} sin x}{2k +3}$ I can't use this solution to verify if it agrees with the standard form.

Comment: Note that clearly we can't get two linearly independent solutions of the form $x^{3/2}$ times a power series. We need to add the conditions on the starting $a_m$ coefficients, which gives $a_{m - 2} = -m (m + 3) a_m \land a_1 = 0$. Then, since $(2 k)!! (2 k + 3)!! = (2 k + 3)!/(2 k + 2)$, one of the solutions is
$$a_0 x^{3/2} \sum_{k \geq 0}
 \frac {(-1)^k (2 k + 2)} {(2 k + 3)!} x^{2 k}.$$